# Is there a way to go to an optional components if the optional parameter is populated in React when using React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm writing a React app where i'm trying to make it so that if the optional paremeter is given i.e id then it would go to a different component otherwise go to the Username component. Is there any way to do this, when i do it this way it only returns the Username Component.

```
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path ="/" exact component={Login}/>
            <Route path ="/name/:username" component={Username}/>
            <Route path ="/name/:username/:id?" component={Id}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should be able to swap the precedence of "/name/:username" and "/name/:username/:id?" (*they should be swapped anyway*) so paths with higher specificity can be matched first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to invert the position of the routes between Username and Id, put the `/name/:username/:id?` before.

Edit:
you don't need the `?` in the end to do that.
A working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-routing-example-lhcohu?file=App.js

Comment: It seems as long as i make id not optional it allows it